# Increase axes labels size with barplot()

Tags: r, plot, label

How can I increase the size of the x and y axes within the following barplot?

I need `'freq'` and `'heights'` to be increased to e.g. `cex = 2`

```
df = read.table(text = 'Heights freq    
                             a  16  
                             b  9   
                             c  8   
                             d  6   
                             e  7   
                             f  4   
                             g  4   
                             h  2   
                             i  3   
                             l  1', header = TRUE)

    x = barplot(df$freq, cex.axis = 1.5, ylab = 'freq', xlab = 'heights')

    axis(1, at = x, c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 
                      'h', 'i'), cex.axis = 1.5) #rename x-axis values
```

It may seems silly but I cannot find a way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change `cex.axis` to `cex.lab` in the barplot code.

```
df = read.table(text = 'Heights freq    
                         a  16  
                         b  9   
                         c  8   
                         d  6   
                         e  7   
                         f  4   
                         g  4   
                         h  2   
                         i  3   
                         l  1', header = TRUE)

x = barplot(df$freq, cex.lab = 2, ylab = 'freq', xlab = 'heights')

axis(1, at = x, c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 
                  'h', 'i'), cex.axis = 1.5) #rename x-axis values
```